# How to iterate array with nested arrays using for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

this code is only iterating the first 9 nos in the nested array.

```
var arr = [[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4]]];

 for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        for(var k = 0; k < arr[j].length; k++){
            console.log(arr[i][j][k]);                      
        };                          
    };    
};
```

Comment: The third loop should use `arr[i][j].length`

Comment: Is it necessary to use `for-loop` for you ?

Comment: Hi Menai -  did you mean there is a better method? pl suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is with the third loop.
Corrected Code -

```
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        for(var k = 0; k < arr[i][j].length; k++){
                 console.log(arr[i][j][k]);                      
        };                               
       };  
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You had missed an iterator on your second loop
Here

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
for( var j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
    for (var k=0;k<arr[i][j].length;k++)
        console.log(arr[i][j][k]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as an alternative way to loop your array.

```
 const iterate = (arr) =>
  arr.forEach((arrOne) =>
    arrOne.forEach((arrTwo) => arrTwo.forEach((value) => console.log(value)))
  );
```